# wx.RadioBox moves while scrolling

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, wxpython

I have a long form that takes user input. `self.metadata` is a long array that represent the form. when I scroll, the **2nd wx.RadioBox** moves when it reaches the top of the container view and **changes it position**.

Kindly provide a workaround or a suggestion how to identify the issue.

- wxPython 4.2.1
- Python 3.9
- Using PyCharm on Mac

  ```
  class DynamicForm(wx.Frame):
   def __init__(self, parent, title):
    super(DynamicForm, self).__init__(parent, title=title, size=(600, 500))

    self.metadata = FormMetadataBuilder.build_views()

    panel = wx.Panel(self)
    scrolled_panel = wx.ScrolledWindow(panel)  # Create a scrolled window
    self.create_ui(scrolled_panel)
    scrolled_panel.SetScrollRate(10, 10)

    sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    sizer.Add(scrolled_panel, 1, wx.EXPAND)  # Add the scrolled window to the sizer

    panel.SetSizer(sizer)
    self.Center()

  def create_ui(self, panel):
    sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

    for item in self.metadata:
        if isinstance(item, LabelView):
            label = wx.StaticText(panel, label=item.label)
            label.SetFont(wx.Font(item.size, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL))
            sizer.Add(label, 0, item.alignment | wx.ALL, 10)

        elif isinstance(item, TextInputView):
            text_input = wx.TextCtrl(panel, style=wx.TE_RIGHT)
            text_input.SetFont(wx.Font(item.size, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL))
            text_input.SetMinSize((200, -1))
            item.user_input = text_input
            sizer.Add(text_input, 0, item.alignment | wx.ALL, 10)

        elif isinstance(item, RadioBoxView):
            radio_box = wx.RadioBox(panel, choices=item.labels)
            radio_box.SetFont(wx.Font(item.size, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL))
            item.user_input = radio_box
            sizer.Add(radio_box, 0, item.alignment | wx.ALL, 10)

    panel.SetSizer(sizer)
  ```

Comment: I suspect you have no response because you have not supplied a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example